# Call to undefined method on calling DB Class

Tags: php

I've been struggling for a little while with this code I should take care of (is not mine which is one of the biggest issues). The original programmer is completely unresponsive and unwilling to help; to improve the situation even further.

The code is for a page where some content is shown, much like an e-Catalog. The flow of items at the bottom consists of 10 items, but I always get a fatal error on calling the php with database information:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::connection() in C:\xampp\htdocs\menonitapp2\api\modelos\Productos.php on line 128

The error occurs here:

```
require_once "db.php"; //the DB info file.
require_once "Producto.php";
require_once "Subasta.php";
class Productos {
 private function __construct() {
  //Actually empty constructor.
 }
//other functions
 public static function buscar_primeros($id, $bus, $counting){
   $min = $counting;
   $max = 10;
   $statement = db::connection()->stmt_init(); //Where the error occurs
   //more stuff after this
 }
}
```

And this is the full db.php file where you access the database:

```
class db {
  private static $servername = "localhost";
  private static $username = "root";
  private static $password = "********";
  private static $dbname = "taquionm_menonitapp";

  private static $connexion = null;

  static function connection() {
    if(is_null(self::$connexion)) {

      self::$connexion = new mysqli(self::$server, self::$username, self::$password, self::$dbname);
      self::$connexion->set_charset("utf8");
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
      }
    }

    return self::$connexion;
  }
}
```

Other relevant information: Using `XAMPP 5.6.8` on Windows 8.1.
PHP Version `5.6.8` as well.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well, but I couldn't find any reference to "DB" in index.php, nor Productos.php. I'll double check anyway

Comment: How are you using that `buscar_primeros()` function? I'm betting a variable scope issue. And why is there a `Productos` class?

Comment: @RobbieAverill PHP class names are case insensitive

Comment: @Phil touche! That's stupid!

Comment: Check for other files named `db.php`, there may be more than one. My guess is there's a file named `db.php` with class `DB` but it does not have a `connection()` method

Comment: @RobbieAverill oh, I know. Variable names are case sensitive but other symbols are not. WTF?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `buscar_primeros()` is **inside** the `Productos` class. I'm using the function in the main page, index.php `$productos=Productos::buscar_primeros(0,38,0);`

Comment: @Phil nope, there is only one file named `db.php` inside the `\api\modelos` folder, where `productos.php` is also located.

Comment: Man, I'm out of ideas here. Could be something with your query. You only tagged as php where you may have needed to add the mysql tag. If you're on a \*NIX system, the filename convention's case-sensitive `productos` and `Productos` are two different animals if that's the case. Have you used error reporting at all? If it's a query issue, error checking on that too? What's line 128? and do you have 2 files named Producto.php and Productos.php (singular and plural). I see `require_once "Producto.php";` yet the error shows as `\Productos.php on line 128`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, it is twisted, but I _sorta_ have an idea of how it works (not my code as I stated, just trying to clean someone's else mess). I double checked every single PHP used by the webpage, and there is no reference to `DB` in uppercase, all of them are lowercase. Yes there are 2 similar PHP, `Productos.php` is a flow of products shown in the page, `Producto.php` is when you actually access a product and get its information.

Comment: If you're not already using error reporting, or if your system's not setup to catch them, consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use it to catch and display. I'm out of ideas now. I sincerely wish you well with this, *cheers*. Wish I could have been of more help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is. `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` is the second line in the `Productos.php` file. The `php_error.log` doesn't give any more information than the page itself too, my log is just full of the same `Fatal Error` I stated. Thanks, I'm gonna need some vacations after this.